# How to run functions that converted by webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a simple library, and I am working with ES6, and I have some require keyword, then, I need to convert this to a version that browsers understand it, **I use webpack to make the browser version of my library.**

Here is an example:

---

*main.js*

```
import Test from './test';

function callMe(){
    console.log("I am damn called!");
}
```

---

*test.js*

```
export default function(string) {
  console.log("This is awesome!");
  [1,2,3].map(n => n + 1);
}
```

---

gulpfile.js (I use Gulp)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel'); 
gulp.task('babel', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/babel'));
});


var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');
gulp.task('webpack', function() {
  return gulp.src('dist/babel/main.js')
    .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

---

Now when I run the Gulp tasks (`babel` and `webpack`), I will get a file which is the result of `webpack` *(and means all require and import are converted now)*

Here is the result of webpack *(I mean the convert result)*:

```js
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/  // The module cache
/******/  var installedModules = {};

/******/  // The require function
/******/  function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/   // Check if module is in cache
/******/   if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/    return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/   // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/   var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/    exports: {},
/******/    id: moduleId,
/******/    loaded: false
/******/   };

/******/   // Execute the module function
/******/   modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/   // Flag the module as loaded
/******/   module.loaded = true;

/******/   // Return the exports of the module
/******/   return module.exports;
/******/  }


/******/  // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/  __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/  // expose the module cache
/******/  __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/  // __webpack_public_path__
/******/  __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/  // Load entry module and return exports
/******/  return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

 "use strict";

 var _test = __webpack_require__(1);

 var _test2 = _interopRequireDefault(_test);

 function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

 function callMe() {
  console.log("I am damn called!");
 }

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

 "use strict";

 Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
   value: true
 });

 exports.default = function (string) {
   console.log("This is awesome!");
   [1, 2, 3].map(function (n) {
     return n + 1;
   });
 };

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

**The first question is, now, how can I execute (and access) the `callMe` function that defined in `main.js` and now bundled by *webpack*?**

The other question is that, the code looks ugly and not simple, is there any way to simplify it?

And I also think `webpack` seems to be something else that just be for converting require to a browser supportable version, and `browserify` had problems with Gulp. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I execute (and access) the `callMe` function that defined in `main.js`?

You can't, because you didn't export it. You should change your code to something like that:

```
import Test from './test';

export default function callMe(){
  console.log("I am damn called!");
}
```

Then you can import it like that:

```
import callMe from 'dist/main.js';
callMe(); // logs "I am damn called!"
```

> The code looks ugly and not simple, is there any way to simplify it?

There's no need to simplify it. There's nothing wrong with bundled code looking ugly, because anyway it's not going to be read by humans.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I have a question. I still can not call the "callMe()" when I run the JavaScript

Comment: Could you please share any resources for that? I do not know about that at all

Comment: @Lash How exactly do you run it? And what error are you getting?

Comment: I mean, when I include the .js file in my web page, I can call the "callMe" function from the Chrome console , the error I get is **callMe is not defined**

Comment: @Lash If you change the [`output.libraryTarget`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) option to `this`, you'll be able to access the exported value as a property of the global object (IOW, it will be a global variable).

Comment: Import is not defined.   How to use it with ES5?

Comment: @0x4f3759df This question asks how to do it with `import`. If you want to do it in ES5, post a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Since searching *how to expose a function using webpack* brought me here and the answer was hidden in the comments I'll post it here to be more visible.

I want the `callMe()` function to be visible on global (window) object when my webpack-bundeled-script is loaded. In my case I want to invoke delyed bootstrap of my Angular2 app on a button click, but that's just implementation detail.

---

So in the `main.js` I export my function:

```
export function callMe(){
  console.log("I am damn called!");
  // And I do more things ;)
}
```

And according to [the webpack docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget), in the `webpack.js` configuration I do:

```
module.exports = {
  entry {
    app: "dist/babel/main.js"
  }, 
  output {
    // My funky output configs...

    libraryTarget: "this"

  }
}
```

That's it. The `this` refers to the global window object as it is loaded using `<script>` tag in my html page.

Sorry to the OP, I don't know the Gulp-webpack configuration. But I thing it might work just passing the above object to the `webpack()` function according to [the gulp-webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html#normal-compilation).