# Webpack . Calling Javascript functions at Window Level

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am webpacking my javascript

```
alert("Loaded out")

function showLoaded() {
    alert("Loadedin")
}
```

Trying to call the function *showloaded* from html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<script>showLoaded()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Loaded out is being displayed by alert , but I can't seem to call the function showLoaded().
Am I missing something obvious here.

Comment: what does bundle.js contain?

Comment: doesn't `webpack` create a closure, to which it puts all your rendered source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also expose your function this way:

```
alert("Loaded out");

function showLoaded() {
    alert("Loadedin");
}

window.showLoaded = showLoaded;
```

Answer (score 1):

Found Answer here,
[How to run functions that converted by webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721816/how-to-run-functions-that-converted-by-webpack) . found answer here.

I had to add

```
output {


    libraryTarget: "this"

  }
```

to my webpack config for making the function visible on global (window) object.

and used export on function

```
export function showLoaded() {
    alert("Loadedin5")
}
```